# Connecting to MySQL with Angular JS

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm attempting to create a database, and then connect that database to angular, so I can display simple blog like messages.

How would I achieve this? I understand that the easiest way would probably be to write a PHP service to retrieve the data from the database and then call that service from angular, but I have no idea where to even start.

Any direction would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Start reading about web-apps...

Comment: You might implent your one `REST` API or install a ready solution for that...